# how to handle pthread_kill to exit program normally

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, pthreads, pthread-exit

When I am giving a sleep of 1 second then i am getting a usual exit but when i comment out `sleep(1)` and compile and run the program i get getting `killed` why is that ?
I know giving sleep is not the right way ,i want to know how to deal a scenario where we have to call pthread kill and make sure thread exit normally | `in a nutshell i want that atleast thread is created and running when pthread_kill is called`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *mythread(void *vargp)
{

        printf("Printing from Thread \n");
//      ...
        ...
        printf("End of thread\n");
}


int main()

{
        pthread_t thread_id;
        printf("main start\n");
        pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, mythread, NULL);
        sleep(1); // <----------- Here
        pthread_kill(thread_id,SIGVTALRM);
}
```

Comment: With the sleep, the thread you're trying to send a signal to probably no longer exists by that point. Always check for errors from functions that report them.

Comment: Any objective here? I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Using [`pthread_kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) is an "extreme" measure. If you find yourself needing to do this, I suggest rethinking your architecture such that your threads perform their work and exit gracefully, including early exit scenarios. Building on the comment above, the man page says _... an attempt to use a thread ID whose lifetime has ended produces undefined behavior..._, so presumably your thread finishes execution before 1 second, and trying to kill it after that invokes UB.

Comment: Using signal 9, aka SIGKILL, means that there is no chance for anything in the program as a whole (not just the signalled thread) to respond.  A process dies when it is sent SIGKILL.  Don't use SIGKILL unless you mean it to be unhandlable.

Comment: 'I suggest rethinking your architecture such that your threads perform their work and never exit until the entire process terminates and the OS kills all the threads.

Comment: how to give enough time so that the thread is created and start running . sleep is not solution how you give time so that atleast first line of thread get start running @MartinJames

Comment: @Shawn In my source code I call pthread create then after some line of code i call pthread kill , the issue is control reaches to pthread_kill before the first line of thread is executed .my question how to make sure atleast thread become up and running when pthread_kill is called